# is there a way to run the java programs that are developed in netbeans in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

i have done my project on netbeans IDE version 6.9.1

And now i tried to switch the platform to eclipse.

i couldn't see any similarities between the 2 IDE's

I couldn't load the java files into the workspace.

please help me out!

Comment: Did you try `File -> Import`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the project configuration and netbeans-specific features you used will of course not be preserved (though I believe netbeans generates ant scripts to build the project, and those should work fine in eclipse, perhaps after some tweaking).

All you really have to do is create a new Java project, choose the existing project's root as location and then configure the source folders and build path (and perhaps some other things) to match the project's structure.

Comment: @ashishkawade: well, WHAT errors? Most likely they are related to project configuration you've failed to replicate. You can't expect to get help based on vague information like "there is something called antbuilder something".